# Multicontent on a wpf button ( Image + Text)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, styles

I would like to create a template for a button. I would like to place an image (on the left) and text on this button.

I tried to make a thing like that:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonImageEtTexte">
<Button Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" Height="27" >
    <Button.Content>
            <Label>
                <Label.Content>Fichiers joints</Label.Content>
                <Label.Foreground>white</Label.Foreground>
                <Label.VerticalAlignment>center</Label.VerticalAlignment>
                <Label.HorizontalAlignment>center</Label.HorizontalAlignment>
            </Label>
            <Border CornerRadius="3">
            <ContentPresenter/>
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#58585a" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DegradeCouleurTheme}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Button.Content>      
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

</Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here is my code with a stackpanel added:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonImageEtTexte">
<Button Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" Height="27" >
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border CornerRadius="3">
                <ContentPresenter/>
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#58585a" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DegradeCouleurTheme}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
            <Label>
                <Label.Content>Fichiers joints</Label.Content>
                <Label.Foreground>white</Label.Foreground>
                <Label.VerticalAlignment>center</Label.VerticalAlignment>
                <Label.HorizontalAlignment>center</Label.HorizontalAlignment>
            </Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Here is my call of the Template :

```
            <Grid Margin ="10,180,10,14">
                <Button Template="{StaticResource BoutonImageEtTexte}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,0,0,0"> 
                    <Image Source="ToolBar_FicJoints.png" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
```

Unfortunately, i only see the image, and , not the text ?
Anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks

Comment: Just wrap 'em in a StackPanel/Grid.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try something easier:

```
<Button>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="yourimage.jpg" />
    <TextBlock>Button content</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the 2 elements in a single element like `StackPanel`

Example:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonImageEtTexte">
    <Button Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" Height="27" >
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border CornerRadius="3">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#58585a" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DegradeCouleurTheme}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                </Border>
                <Label>
                    <Label.Content>Fichiers joints</Label.Content>
                    <Label.Foreground>white</Label.Foreground>
                    <Label.VerticalAlignment>center</Label.VerticalAlignment>
                    <Label.HorizontalAlignment>center</Label.HorizontalAlignment>
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the stackPanel idea ! But, can i use ContentPresenter in order to specify the Text and the Image in the call of this Template ? I would like to specify the Text and the image in my Page1.xaml ? Is it possible ? I tried but...no succes :(

Comment: I edit my first post. I made your modification but i only see the image, not the text. Have you an idea please ? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that creating a button with an image inside, will give you an ugly border, that should be avoided.  A workaround is to create an event for an image.

For instance, you can create an `OnMouseOver` event that switches the button to, either a new image, text, or an image with text, or really anything you choose.

You can also create an `OnClick` event that could trigger the image to do a task as if it was a button.

What I have done in a situation like this, was create an image that looks like a custom button, then create the same image, and modify it so that a border appeared around it.

I made an OnMouseOver to switch the images (so the bordered image appears), and an OnClick to do the function I required.

You can then use this template for any other situation you have with custom buttons.

Hope this helps!